# How to assign predefined weights for words in Bag of Words

Tags: python, machine-learning, vector, deep-learning, vectorization

I have a list of words in Bag of word. Each word has a predefined weight (value between 0-1). How can I assign those weights to each words. I used Count Vectorizer to get number of words occurrences when user given text. I need to multiply both number of occurrences and relevant weights to get relevant word value.

Comment: Tell me if I understand you correctly. You have a list of words. You want to assign a predefined weight to each word in this list correct?

Comment: Yes. User given sentence or post is vectorized through the BOW. Then it will count no of occurrences of word which has in user given sentence. I need to multiply these occurrence and their weights of relevant word.